# Applying css to a table contained in an iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I will be serving 3rd party content to other sites through an iframe.  The content will be presented in a table.  Is there any way to use internal style sheets where the defintions are defined **within** the iframe??  I have read that internal style sheets should only be defined in the head section.  External css is not an option.

Here is an example of the content that would show **inside** the iframe.

```
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    .className{
            background-color: #444444;
    }
    </STYLE>


    <table>
     <tr>
        <td class="className">
           Column 1.
        </td> 
        <td>
           Column 2.
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Or is the only alternative to use **inline css**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe content should be complete html/xhtml. What you have listed in your question will work but I can't see a reason not to have full html tags including `<head>`.

---

When you declare an iframe, you should belinking to a complete html file:

```
<iframe src ="myIframeContents.html">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

myIframeContents.html should be treated like any other html file. It should have tags for html, head, body, etc. This means that you can place `<style>` tags directly into the `<head>` just like you normally would.

myIframeContents.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
        .className{ 
            background-color: #444444; 
        } 
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
       <table> 
           <tr> 
              <td class="className"> 
                 Column 1. 
              </td>  
              <td> 
                 Column 2. 
              </td> 
           </tr> 
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean there would <head> section, and also even a <body> section?

Comment: Yes... an Iframe should contain a complete HTML file. See edits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

that method there will work.
 tags are supposed to be used in the head of a document, but can appear in other places as well and be local to that branch of the DOM, including iframes

Comment: Thanks.  What I have read about using iframes outside of the <head> is that it can cause flicker.  Will the flicker apply here?

Comment: flicker can occur for a number of reasons. However, iframes should always be in th body of the containing document... not in the head.

Comment: Oh - sorry.  I phrased that statement totally wrong.  I meant to say: What I have read about using internal css outside of the <head> is that it can cause flicker.